# Entity Framework generating a bad query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using EntityFramework 6.3.0 in .Net 4.7.2
I have this code in C#

```
int userId = 1;
string statusValue = StatusCodes.Failing; // This is a string for anyone wondering, not an Enum
return (from statusRow in DbContext.Statuses
    where statusRow.UserId == userId
          && statusRow.Status == statusValue
          && statusRow.Times > 0
    orderby statusRow.CreatedAtDateTimeOffset descending
    select statusRow).FirstOrDefault();
```

EntityFramework is generating this query

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 int = 1;
DECLARE @p__linq__1 nvarchar = 'Failing';

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Project1].[Times] AS [Times], 
    [Project1].[CreatedAtDateTimeOffset] AS [CreatedAtDateTimeOffset], 
    [Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
        [Extent1].[Times] AS [Times], sOverridden], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedAtDateTimeOffset] AS [CreatedAtDateTimeOffset], 
        [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
        FROM [dbo].[Statuses] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) AND (([Extent1].[Status] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[Status] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND ([Extent1].[Times] > 0)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[CreatedAtDateTimeOffset] DESC
```

The problem is the second line where it declares p__linq_1.
It is setting the type to nvarchar, which sql server then defaults to 1 character in length.  Because of this the query returns no records when there are records it should find.
The Status column in the model is defined as

```
[StringLength(50)]
public string Status { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Status")]
public virtual xStatus StatusValue { get; set; }
```

I have also tried MaxLength(50) instead of StringLength.  But the generated query remains the same.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Update: This may be the same issue as [String matching problem in Entity framework. Works for a string literal but not for a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557163/string-matching-problem-in-entity-framework-works-for-a-string-literal-but-not)

But using string.Compare as specified in that ticket does not work either.

---

After further debugging on my side I've found that it was a user error on my part and not an issue in Entity Framework.

Comment: What output do you get when you directly run the generated SQL in ManagementStudio? Do you get the expected output?

Comment: When I run the query in SSMS I get no results.
If I change the second line to have ...nvarchar(50) = 'Failing';
Then it works correctly.

Comment: Are you saying that with `DECLARE @p__linq__1 nvarchar = 'Failing'; `, it gives you the expected output?

Comment: Also, `string statusValue = StatusCodes.Failing;` what is StatusCodes, looks like an `enum`, how are you assigning it directly to a `string` variable, would it not need a `.ToString()`?

Comment: No, ```DECLARE @p__linq__1 nvarchar = 'Failing';``` doesn't find rows where Status is set to 'Failing'.  ```DECLARE @p__linq__1 nvarchar(50) = 'Failing';``` returns the rows.  Entity Framework is generating the DECLARE statement without the length which SQL Server interprets as a nvarchar with length of 1.

Comment: Could you check the actual type of `[Status]` in the database schema? Also which version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: [Status] is of type VARCHAR(50).  I've modified EntityFramework to specify type VARCHAR for the column, it has no effect other than generating the query with type varchar instead of nvarchar.  Still doesn't specify the size and so the query fails to return any records.

Comment: Do you have anything specific to this field on your `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method? If so could you add it to your question?

Comment: Nothing is specified on this field in DbContext.OnModelCreating

Comment: Remove the StatusCodes.Failing; and substitute by a real string "Failing"; then you will realice where is your issue.

Comment: @dfortun Doing that makes no difference and if it did then there would be even more problems.  Shouldn't matter if a string comes from a constant, property, method or hardcoded.

Comment: @mkinkade - Just for sanity check, are conditions on other varchar columns being interpreted appropriately by EF, I'm trying to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the type to be `varchar` instead of nvarchar, using below change:

```
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Status { get; set; }
```

With above change the EF query will generate the parameter as `varchar`.

Comment: EF will generate the query as varchar, but it still doesn't specify the size and so the query still fails to return any rows.

Comment: can you try with length defined in colum attribute as `[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(50)")]`. In that case, you can remove `StringLength` attribute

Comment: I tried that already.  Get an exception about not being able to find the type VARCHAR(50).  I think that may work for EF Core, but we're not using EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

`StringLength` appears to be getting ignored.  This bit here is perking my interest:

```
[ForeignKey("Status")]
public virtual xStatus StatusValue { get; set; }
```

Can you temporarily comment this out, either in whole or the `[ForeignKey]` attribute? I know this would break anything referencing that StatusValue property expecting an entity, but I might suspect that the PK of this xStatus entity is somehow affecting/overriding the Status column on Statuses.  That relationship seems really suspect that there would be some "type" association mapped to this string value rather than via Statuses' PK.

If that fixes the query, check the Status column or PK on this xStatus entity to see if it has a `[StringLength]` attribute as well.